# innerHTML não apresenta o object

Tags: javascript

Estou usando o innerHTML para preencher uma página, a estrutura dela vai tranquilo, o problema está nas variáveis que contém objetos, elas aparecem escritas por extenso em vez de mostrar seus valores, tentei adicionar .text() no nome dela e resultou numa página em branco, o que mais deu certo até agora foi o código abaixo

```
$('#btnPrint').click(function() {
           var prtContent = document.getElementById("nome");
           console.log(prtContent);
           var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
           WinPrint.document.body.innerHTML="<body onload='javascript:window.print();'><style>@font-face {font-family: Evogria;src: url('/files/Evogria.otf') format('opentype');}html{font-family: Evogria;}body{zoom: 100%;height:0;width:354px;margin-top:414px;bottom:0;margin-bottom:0;padding:0;margin-left:121px; margin-right:18px;font-weight:bold;}</style>"
           WinPrint.document.body.innerHTML+=`${prtContent}`;
           WinPrint.document.close();
           WinPrint.focus();
           WinPrint.print();
           document.getElementById('nome').remove()
           WinPrint.close();
        });

        }
    });
```

que retorna um output de "[object HTMLTableCellElement]", alguém sabe dizer se a variável deixou de puxar o objeto, ou se há algo errado com a forma como estou tentando apresentá-lo?

Comment: Tente substituir a linha `WinPrint.document.body.innerHTML+=`${prtContent}`;` por `WinPrint.document.body.append(prtContent)`

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você for dar o append no prtContent, use prtContent.outerHtml

```
WinPrint.document.body.innerHTML += prtContent.outerHTML;
```